# How to read values from MultiCheckbox in Zend

Tags: php, zend-form-element

i have a problem with this Zend form element, how can i read the elements status of Multicheckbox?

```
    $type= new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('typer');
    $type->setLabel('Type');
    $type->addMultiOptions(array(
                        '1' => 'type1',
                        '2' => 'type2'



  ));
```

Thanks for the support!...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieve it with getValue()

```
$type->getValue();
```

It'll be an array with ONLY the elements that were checked.

i.e

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="campaign_id" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="campaign_id" value="2" />
```

will return an array like this (IF both are checked)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

if say only checkbox 2 was checked the array will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
```

If no checkboxes were checked the getValue() will return NULL